# How do you CAST a string to a column alias in Presto

Tags: sql, hadoop, presto

I have a Presto SQL Query that I need to make a column alias out of a text string:

```
SELECT column1, column2 AS CAST(column3[0] AS ???)
```

But I am unsure of the data type I need to cast the string as to be a valid alias. Or is there a better way to name one column after a string parsed out of another column?

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: That's not possible in pure SQL. A query returns a fixed, predefined set of columns. What you actually trying to achieve?